# Upgrade FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have fullCalendar version 2.9 and I wanna upgrade it to the newest v5. In my project I just have a plugin folder called fullcalender with a js and css file. If i download the v5 zip theres a lib and examples folder and im just not sure what to do with them.

Ive looked everywhere online too, can't find any guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**lib** folder is generally where the core application source code is stored. You should include the *css* and *javascript* files from the **lib** folder into your current project.